# How to make my PHP files call the password from the database properly?

Tags: php, mysql, encryption

I am currently working on a website, it has a sign up PHP file that sends data to a database. For security measures, I set up a password encryption file that encrypts the password that the user enters, so that it is impossible to find in the database. Unfortunately, when the user tries to connect to the database from the log in PHP file, it denies them access to log in because the code connects to the database passwords, but it doesn't "sanitize" the password from it's encryption code, and the password isn't recognized by the server. I will provide my codes below:

Signup.php

```
$p = $_POST['p'];    
$cryptpass = crypt($p);
include_once ("php_includes/randStrGen.php");
$p_hash = randStrGen(20)."$cryptpass".randStrGen(20);
```

Login.PHP

```
$p = md5($_POST['p']);
```

How do I change the Login.PHP line provided above so that it sanitizes the password from it's encryption value to the password the user actually knows and entered in the first place?

p.s. $p= The Password that the user enters

Comment: You should look more into your method of your password encrypting...there are somewhat of standards when encrypting and decrypting.

Comment: Okay. I am not an expert, obviously from what you can see. Is there another method that you recommend?

Comment: Yes...give me a few minutes

Comment: Over all, the answer I gave you gives you the ability to decrypt the password back into the original readable format. If you only want to encrypt, but not decrypt, you can then just salt and hash the password before inserting into the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to add a second answer here, which is more of a safe guard when it comes to any user input you get that will be inserted or drawn from a database. When you `MySql` you want to sanitize any user input to prevent database injection which is the easiest way to break into a database.

Here is a great sanitation script. Start by making a separate PHP file and copy/paste this code into it.

```
<?php
// Sanitize User Input
function sanitize($data){

    // apply stripslashes if magic_quotes_gpc is enabled
    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()){ 
        $data = stripslashes($data);
    }
    // a mySQL connection is required before using this function
    $data = mysql_real_escape_string($data); 

    return $data;
}
?>
```

Now include this page on any page that you will be interacting with the db

```
 <?php require("sanitize.php"); ?>
```

Note: Before calling the function you must already be connected to your db
IE: `mysql_connect("mysql",$mysqlusername,$mysqlpassword);`

From here on out it is very simple. Say you assign a variable from a post like so

```
 $password = $_POST["password"];
```

To sanitize this input you would do this

```
 $password = sanitize($password);
```

This helps prevent MySql injections by removing certain characters relevant to modifying or revealing database information.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Beautiful! Sorry for the late response, and thank you very much. I really appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so once you get the password from the user you will want to encrypt it when inserting into your database.  This requires an extra piece of data that is called "salt".
Salt is unique and you decide what you want it to be. But you will need it to encrypt and decrypt so it's important you do not lose it! I keep it in its own file and use an include whenever I need it.  The following is PHP

```
 $key_salt = 'lettersandnumbers';
```

Now for the password encrypting
Say you have the username and password in variables like so...

```
 $user_id = "usersId";
 $password = "usersPassword";
```

This is the way to put them into the database...
Create a variable with the following data

```
 $insertdata = sprintf("INSERT INTO $table (user_id, password,) VALUES ('%s', AES_ENCRYPT('%s', '$key_salt'))", $user_id, $password);
 mysql_query($insertdata);
```

Notice the `AES_ENCRYPT('%s', '$key_salt')` This is what is making the encryption and see how it uses the `$key_salt` along with the `'%s'` (which is the `$password`)

The combination of these makes it nearly impossible to crack

This will decrypt the password and put it into  a variable then you can do what you want with it after that....

```
 $results = mysql_query("
    SELECT AES_DECRYPT(password, '$key_salt') as password FROM $table where AES_DECRYPT(password, '$key_salt')='$password'");
 $row = mysql_fetch_array($results);
 $decryptedpassword = $row['password'];
```

Comment: Okay. So if my current encryption file is called 'RandStrGen.php', than that is what I would put in place of 'lettersandnumbers'? That file is my salt file. I understand everything except for that.

Comment: Sidenote: One shouldn't "encrypt" but to "hash" a password.

Comment: Correct, the `$key_salt` would be just be a variable that you create and put in its own separate file. Then include that file on any page you are encrypt or decrypting.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That is up for debate, and we could sit here for quite sometime going back and forth. Xiaoyun Wang published an effective collision attack against hashing in 2005, and its strength is now seen as considerably below its design strength - thus in cryptographic terms it is "broken".

Comment: I found the article(s), very interesting. @VIDesignz

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yeah man...I mean, if you look at the huge target database breach and the countless others lately...the reality is nothing is really safe anymore :( It's hard to stay ahead of the game.

Comment: I couldn't have said it any better; you took the words right out of my mouth. Absolute madness. @VIDesignz

Comment: @TheCreator I added a second answer which is geared towards sanitizing user input to help prevent database injection. This would be on top of encrypting/hashing passwords and such. The more defenses you have, the better!

Answer (score 0):

Do not concatenate crypted password with random characters unless you save them also in database, otherwise - you will never be able to compare user input with saved encrypted password. Just use:

```
$p_hash = $cryptpass;
```

and in Login.php script do not use `md5($_POST['p']);` which is different hashing method, but use also `crypt()` function:

```
$p = crypt($_POST['p']);
```

Comment: I guess I left out that bit of info. When the user enters the password, it gets encrypted by the script, and the encrypted password gets stored in the database. I am not sure if this is the best way to go about this, but I am semi-new to PHP, and I have yet to reach the "Thinking outside of the box stage" like I have with HTML and CSS.

Comment: Do you know of a pre-made, and stable, signup and login set of PHP files I could use and edit to fit my specifications?

Comment: Actually, I always write signup and login procedures by myself, so I am not aware of any pre-made, ready-to-plugin files to suite you.

Comment: Okay. I am not very good at PHP, but I am just trying to make a site that allows users to sign up, activate their account, sign in, and log out. I have made all of those possible except for the sign in part. My password encryption system doesn't work when the user wants to sign in. I need to find a way to decrypt the password when the user wants to sign in.